# upload multiple pdf contar paginas

Tags: pdf

Estimados una consulta como puedo realizar algo como esto no me complica mucho el upload multiple, lo que no tengo claro es en el ejemplo que adjunto si subes un .pdf que contenga varias paginas te las cuenta y te suma o calcula las paginas que contenga el .pdf alguna idea como implementar algo así. sobre todo la parte donde cuenta las paginas.

creo que he podido ver que lo hacen con esta librería la parte del upload multiple pero la manera de contar las paginas por .pdf no lo tengo claro alguna ayuda o idea.

me parece que se apoyan de esta librera

https://www.dropzonejs.com/

la referencia de la idea es esta

https://twpc.printjob.com/productOrder/order/plan-printing

Saludos,

Comment: Hola @SixtoMujica, ya sabes que tienes que intentar algo para que podamos echarte una mano...

Comment: Amigo antes de postear tu pregunta deberías de ayudarnos tu a nosotros indicándonos un poco de código con algún avance en algún pequeño proyecto ya que puede que las aplicaciones de estas herramientas puedan ser distintas de acuerdo al caso :)

Answer (score 0):

Hola gracias por la respuestas si tienen razon. Lo que pasa es, que no he codifcado nada. Y creo que mi pedido no se comprendio no vo voy por el tema que me ayuden a codificar algo solo estaba pidiendo sugerencias que puedo probar. Por ejemplo como los links que deje. Donde me puedan sugerir. prueba esta librería. Framework. Plugins etc. Para revisar y poder intentar replicar el demo o idea que deje por donde debería empezar. Solo indicar que podría probar. No tanto ayuda en codificar.

Espero se entienda

Saludos

Comment: si ese es el caso, probé subir un pdf y creo que el aviso que aparece cuando termina de cargar el archivo se parece mucho a [sweetalert2](https://sweetalert2.github.io/) y para Vue.. pueder ver este link en donde se ocupa una librería para renderizar pero que además cuentas las hojas del pdf [Renderizar documentos PDF con Vue.js](https://styde.net/renderizar-documentos-pdf-con-vue-js/)